# swift collection view expandable tags cell constraint bug

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

if it would be a long text i have this constraint bug

here is the bug picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjpQp.jpg)

i just found that code and do it as same but i can not understand exactly

flowlayout code

```
class TagFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let attributesForElementsInRect = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
        var newAttributesForElementsInRect = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        var leftMargin: CGFloat = 0.0;

        for attributes in attributesForElementsInRect! {
            if (attributes.frame.origin.x == self.sectionInset.left) {
                leftMargin = self.sectionInset.left
            } else {
                var newLeftAlignedFrame = attributes.frame
                newLeftAlignedFrame.origin.x = leftMargin
                attributes.frame = newLeftAlignedFrame
            }
            leftMargin += attributes.frame.size.width + 8
            newAttributesForElementsInRect.append(attributes)
        }

        return newAttributesForElementsInRect
    }
}
```

TAG CELL CODE

```
class TagCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var tagLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var maxConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var tagView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var photo: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.tagLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 22.0
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        self.maxConstraint.constant = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 8 * 2 - 8 * 2
    }

}
```

IN THE MAIN VIEW USING THIS ABOUT FLOW LAYOUT

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        self.configureCell(cell: self.sizingCell!, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        return self.sizingCell!.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
    }
```

and this is the xib file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhDk6.jpg)

i've been tried a lot of hours to fix that issue i couldn't do it please help me to find the solution :(

Comment: As written, it is unclear what your actual issue is. Can you be more specific about what is going wrong and what the desired end result is?

Comment: if the text inside of the cell is long , there will be sliding in the collection view

Comment: as i showed you at the first image i dont want to slide any cell